# Create randomly sized (within a certain range) arrays over many iterations

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create many arrays consisting of random numbers and of random size between the range of, say, 1 and 20 elements. My code works SOMETIMES.

I am using a random number between my desired range to determine the array size. If the first iteration produces an array size of value 10, say, then for some reason my code does not want to create any arrays of size larger than 10. Various arrays will be created (and the list of those arrays will be outputed) until a certain iteration produces a random number larger than 10. Then I get this error:

> **Array index out of range numbers->[11] valid upto numbers[9]**

"numbers" is the name of the array. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
srand(time(0));
int j, flag = 0;
int temp;
int rand=1;

for(int t=0; t<50; t++)
{
    int length = rand()% 20 + 1;
    cout<<"length is " << length << endl;
    int numbers[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=rand();
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

    for(j=0; (j<=length); j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<(length-1); i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i+1]<numbers[i])
            {
                temp=numbers[i];
                numbers[i]=numbers[i+1];
                numbers[i+1]=temp;
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of Swaps : " << flag << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with the array length not updating?

Comment: The code looks OK, I don't see anything suspicious.

Comment: Plus, I can't reproduce the issue on my computer. Is it the actual code, or just a simplified version of it? Post the actual code.

Comment: I posted my entire code. I am still getting the same issues. It doesn't want to create arrays larger than 9 elements. It seems to be dependent on the first array length created.

Comment: `int numbers[length]` is non-standard. Idk if that can cause this problem, though. None of the `i`s in the last loop are secretely `j`s in your program, are they?

Comment: Perhaps I should use vectors instead of arrays?  Would I still be able to sort the elements the way I am doing here?

Comment: Yes, `vector` is designed to work like that. Also, I edited your question to improve the formatting and removed the tags for random and root as they were irrelevant, but I accidentally deleted the closing parenthetical on the second `for` loop, if you wanted to put it back (sorry!).

Comment: This can't be the exact code you're running, it's missing a closing parenthesis on the second `for`, and this definition `int rand=1;` would lead to a compile error when you try to call the `rand()` function.

Comment: Thank you everybody! I ended up using `vector` and it works great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bob__ wrote, allocating variable length arrays is not C++ standard. It might work sometimes on specific compilers, but it may break on others.

But there are good alternatives. You can allocate dynamic memory with `new`. For instance:

```
int *array = new int[size];
array[0] = 3;
array[1] = 5;
cout << array[1];
delete [] array;
```

Don't forget to delete the memory with `delete` afterwards.

Or you could use `vector<int>`. It's a STL-container, that was made for exactly this purpose.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
...
vector<int> vec(size);
vec[0] = 3;
vec[1] = 5;
cout << vec[1];
```

Comment: **And** `std::vector` is part of the standard. So here in this case is really no reason to use an `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable Length Arrays are not in C++ standard, but only offered as extension by some compilers. I wouldn't trust them and you don't really need anything like that in your code.
You can declare your array outside the outer for loop as you know its max lenght:

```
#define MAXL 20

int numbers[MAXL];

for ...
    int length = rand() % MAXL + 1;
    ...
```

Besides, if you are implementing a bubble sort I think that the condition of the inner i loop should be i < length - j

Answer (score 0):

1. `rand` is used in two contexts. As a variable `int rand` and as a function `std::rand()`. I'd suggest to delete any `using namespace std;` but since the variable is not needed anyways you could as well delete `int rand = 1;`. Note that `rand()` is a C function. You *may* use it but IMHO `std::rand()` is more pure C++.
2. `int numbers[length];` will not compile because `length` is a non-constant. Use `std::vector<int> numbers(length);` instead.

And that's about it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    std::srand(time(0));
    int j, flag = 0;
    int temp;

    for (int t = 0; t < 50; t++)
    {
        int length = std::rand() % 20 + 1;
        std::cout << "length is " << length << std::endl;
        std::vector<int> numbers(length);;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = std::rand();
            std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
        }

        for (j = 0; (j <= length); j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i])
                {
                    temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = temp;
                    flag++;
                }
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Number of Swaps : " << flag << std::endl;
    }
}
```